# Recursively find adjacent coordinates for n-dimensional array

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples

For any tuple of coordinates I am given (ex. (2,2) or (1,2,3) or (4,5,6,7,8), etc.), how can I get a list of all the adjacent coordinates.
So that,

```
find_adjacents((2,2))    

  >>[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

and

```
find_adjacents((2,2,2,2))

would return something with 3^4-1 elements
```

You can ignore edge cases for this (imagine indices range from -inf to inf)

Comment: "All the adjacent coordinates" is vague; what exactly do you mean? Why is that the expected output? And why do you want to do it recursively?

Comment: Sorry. I mean anything with elements within 1 of each the specified coordinate elements(including 'corners'). The corner adjacent elements of (1,1,1) would be 000,200,002,020,220,022,202,222.

Comment: I see - but not including the input itself?

Comment: Yep. So it will always be 3^4-1 elements rather than 3^4

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this. The Cartesian product of the ranges will include the input itself, so we need to remove it afterwards. `list.pop` works for this, because the product is generated in order, such that the input itself will always be exactly the middle element.

```py
from itertools import product

def neighbours(t):
    ranges = [(x-1, x, x+1) for x in t]
    result = list(product(*ranges))
    result.pop(len(result) // 2)
    return result
```

Examples (formatted for readability):

```py
>>> neighbours( (1, 2) )
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),
 (1, 1),         (1, 3),
 (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]

>>> neighbours( (1, 1, 1) )
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2),
 (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2),

 (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 1, 0),            (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2),

 (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2),
 (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion:

```
def combos(d, c = []):
  if not d:
     yield c
  else:
     yield from [i for b in range(d[0]-1, d[0]+2) for i in combos(d[1:], c+[b])]

vals = (2,2)
print(list(combos(vals)))
print(list(combos((1, 1, 1))))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```